# How to perform cron-like scheduling using Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, cron

I'm looking for ideas (or libraries if anyone knows any) about how to use cron-like syntax for scheduling kotlin coroutines to be run.

Ideally, the solution should have the following aspects:

1. Accept proper cron syntax to do scheduling
2. Trigger coroutine (suspend) functions to be run in my specified scope (e.g: Most likely not on the main thread)